# How to find the Google Analytics account that tallies with a GA ID?

Tags: google-analytics

I've posted on the following link, which I thought was the correct place, but have had no response yet.  Is there a better way to get someone at Google to look into this for me?

https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Google-Analytics-Account-Access/Can-t-locate-the-correct-account-for-an-analytics-UA-tracking-ID/td-p/1244552

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you logged into GA via each email address to check if any have access to that GA Account/Property? Would be the quickest way to check if any have access.

There is a GA Account Access troubleshooter provided via the following link
https://support.google.com/analytics/troubleshooter/7264014

It will also take you through the steps of doing a GA account recovery if one is needed. Keep in mind, once the necessary steps are completed and you submit the info a response will usually take 7-10 days.